# Model-data keeps saving as undefined or null

Tags: ember.js

This should be a pretty simple issue, but I cannot seem to understand why my data keeps being saved as null or undefined.   I have tried multiple adapters, different databases, and several methods from tutorials and blog posts and all data saves as "null" or "undefined"

Background:  Ember 1.13.2   Ember-data 1.13.4.   I'm trying to not use controllers but understand I may have to until routable components are a thing.

So:
    /app/models/person.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({

  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Then I have my pod...  /app/pods/person.

So  /app/pods/person/route.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

model() {
  return this.store.findAll('person');
},

actions: {

  create() {
    var newPerson = this.store.createRecord('person');
    newPerson.save();

}  }  });
```

And /app/pods/person/template.hbs

```
{{input value=model.firstName}}
{{input value=model.lastName}}

<button {{action "create"}}> Create </button>
```

So the data goes into the input, and if I do a {{model.firstName}} I see it binding right on the screen.   It's just that when I click on "create" to try to save it, ember-data saves both fields as "null" or "undefined".   Any idea why?

Comment: You're creating a person with no first name or last name--what did you expect to happen? Try `this.store.createRecord('person', { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' })`.

Comment: Well, the objective was that the {{input }} helper would feed in the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the values of the model (bound to inputs) to the new record. Pass an object as 2nd param of createRecord().

```
var model = this.get('model');

var newPerson = this.store.createRecord('person', {
  firstName: model.get('firstName'),
  lastName: model.get('lastName')
});
```

See [this post](http://codepen.io/asommer70/blog/creating-with-ember-data-post) for a longer example.